# Tengo un problema con mis tabs, quedan un espacio grande debajo y no puedo quitarlo

Tags: javascript, html, css

espero tengan un excelente día.

Estoy haciendo unas tabs y tengo dos problemas: el primero es que dentro de ellas va un texto desplegable, conseguí hacer el desplegable hacia abajo pero lamentablemente cuando se tiene que abrir, se estira y se pierde la redondez del recuadro principal, quisiera saber cómo hacer porque me gustaría que el recuadro arriba se quedara fijo y solo desplegara hacia abajo, intenté con las propiedades y las posiciones, pero nada me ha servido.

El otro asunto es que me queda un espacio enorme debajo de las tabs porque claro sería el espacio cuando se despliega el ver más. ¿Habría forma de quitarlo?

Gracias de antemano a todos por sus respuestas.

Este es el código:

```js
let filter_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn');
let tab_items = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');

for (let i = 0; i < filter_btn.length; i++) {
  filter_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < filter_btn.length; j++) {
      filter_btn[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
    let select_tab = filter_btn[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
    filter_btn[i].classList.add('active');
    for (let t = 0; t < tab_items.length; t++) {
      document.querySelector('.tab-filter-item-container').style.height =
        tab_items[t].scrollHeight + 'px';
      if (tab_items[t].classList.contains(select_tab)) {
        tab_items[t].classList.add('select_tab');
      } else {
        tab_items[t].classList.remove('select_tab');
      }
    }
  });
}

for (let th = 0; th < tab_items.length; th++) {
  document.querySelector('.tab-filter-item-container').style.height =
    tab_items[th].scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
:root {
  --container: 120rem;
  --primary: hsl(201.43, 13.21%, 58.43%);
  --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --white-light: hsl(0, 0%, 99%);
  --box-shadow: hsl(220, 7.32%, 91.96%);
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
.body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  max-width: 160%;
  padding: 0 0rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}
.section-heading {
  margin: 3rem 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.section-heading::before,
.section-heading::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.section-heading::before {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--primary);
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
.section-heading::after {
  bottom: -0.4rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid var(--primary);
  background: var(--box-shadow);
}
.tab-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto 9rem auto;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .tab-container {
    top:90px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.tab-filter-container {
  width:90%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left:200px;
  align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.filter-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0.8rem 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.filter-btn.active {
  background: #000000;
  color: var(--white);
}
.tab-filter-item-container {
  background: var(--white);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0rem 3rem;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(29rem, 1fr));
  place-items: center start;
}

.tab-img1 {
    z-index:2;
  width: 40rem;
padding-top:30px;
  margin-left:20px;
  position:relative;
}
.tab-heading {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.tab-heading2 {
  top:-200px;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.tab-item.select_tab {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #ffffff;
  animation: feadIn 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background: var(--primary);
  padding: 0.6rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  color: var(--white);
}

.fondo{z-index:-1;
margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left:-450px;
position:absolute;
width: 95%;}

@keyframes feadIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}




.box1{
    border-radius:20px !important;
    position: absolute;
  top:50%;
    left:20%;
    transform: translate(-20%,-50%);
    background-color: #69BBFE;
  padding-top:80px;
  padding-left:250px;
  padding-right:280px;
  padding-bottom:90px
  font-size:17px;
    width: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
.box1 input[name="readmore"]{
    display: none;
}
.box1 .des{
  left:230px;
  top:-20px;
  border-radius:20px !important;
  background-color:#9AD1FE;
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  padding-right:40px;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 170px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color:#000000;
  z-index:100;
}
.box1 .des:before{
    position: relative;
  color:#000000;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    content:'';
}
.box1 .button{
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position:relative;
  left:230px;
  font-size:15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000000;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.box1 label{  border-radius:20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:110px;
    height:30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box1 label::before{

    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:attr(data-more);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box1 input[name="readmore"]:checked ~ .content label::before{
    content:attr(data-less);
}
.box1 input[name="readmore"]:checked ~ .content .des{
    max-height: 400px;
}
.box1 input[name="readmore"]:checked ~ .content .des::before{
    height: 0px;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
}
.content::before{
    position: relative;
    bottom:40px;
    right:5px;
    width:50px;
    height: 70px;
    content:'';
    background-color:#9AD1FE
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
.content::after{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    transform: translate(0%,50%);
    width:200px;
    height: 150px;
    content:'';
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
.box input[name="readmore"]:checked ~ .content::before{
    bottom:80%;
    right:100%;
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
.box input[name="readmore"]:checked ~ .content::after{
    transform: translate(75%,55%) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tab Components</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-filter-container">
          <li class="filter-btn active body" data-tab="web-design">
            <ion-icon name="desktop-outline"></ion-icon>
            MARKETING DIGITAL
          </li>
          <li class="filter-btn body" data-tab="web-development">
            <ion-icon name="logo-nodejs"></ion-icon>
            ESTRATEGIAS INTEGRALES
          </li>
          
          
          
          
        </div>
        <div class="tab-filter-item-container">
          <div class="tab-item web-design select_tab">
            <div class="tab-content-left">
              <img
                src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Group-149.png"
                alt="web design"
                class="tab-img1"
              />
              

            </div>
            <div class="tab-content-right">
             <div class="box1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="readmore" id="readmore 2">
        <div class="content body">
            <div class="des"><h1 class="tab-heading">UI UX Design</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas sequi consectetur culpa eius aliquam, deserunt voluptatem quos distinctio atque, ad consequatur nemo totam fugit mollitia molestias natus exercitationem veritatis libero porro debitis? Et porro consequatur minima placeat harum iusto labore sed perspiciatis accusamus voluptatum ipsam esse illum fugiat, possimus vitae dolores officiis tenetur provident explicabo beatae nostrum aspernatur doloremque quos! Deserunt quisquam facere doloremque hic nisi, at earum facilis voluptatibus exercitationem distinctio! Deleniti, voluptatem ratione minima incidunt laboriosam repudiandae maiores cumque maxime fugit ex dolore ullam iusto, id ea dolorum reiciendis eaque asperiores. Magni ab tenetur doloremque! Harum totam laboriosam, quam corrupti dolorum nostrum ullam, temporibus expedita minima fuga, sapiente pariatur voluptatibus? Nesciunt repellat labore totam sunt porro velit excepturi assumenda distinctio non? Eveniet a magnam doloribus odit voluptatum earum maiores ipsum fuga recusandae aliquam. Praesentium autem vel ipsum omnis eligendi ab et, quaerat nobis culpa dolores laborum neque harum consequatur in mollitia est asperiores excepturi qui, veniam sit officia nisi id libero! Natus ex, error eos aliquid rem, quis illum ratione fugit magnam non laborum dolores dignissimos reiciendis aspernatur nostrum cumque 

            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <label for="readmore 2"
                    data-more="READ MORE"
                    data-less="READ LESS"
                ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-item web-development">
              <img
             src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Group-149.png"
                alt="web development"
                class="tab-img1"
              />
            <div class="tab-content-left">
              <div class="box1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="readmore" id="readmore 3">
        <div class="content body">
            <div class="des"><h1 class="tab-heading">UI UX Design</h1>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas sequi consectetur culpa eius aliquam, deserunt voluptatem quos distinctio atque, ad consequatur nemo totam fugit mollitia molestias natus exercitationem veritatis libero porro debitis? Et porro consequatur minima placeat harum iusto labore sed perspiciatis accusamus voluptatum ipsam esse illum fugiat, possimus vitae dolores officiis tenetur provident explicabo beatae nostrum aspernatur doloremque quos! Deserunt quisquam facere doloremque hic nisi, at earum facilis voluptatibus exercitationem distinctio! Deleniti, voluptatem ratione minima incidunt laboriosam repudiandae maiores cumque maxime fugit ex dolore ullam iusto, id ea dolorum reiciendis eaque asperiores. Magni ab tenetur doloremque! Harum totam laboriosam, quam corrupti dolorum nostrum ullam, temporibus expedita minima fuga, sapiente pariatur voluptatibus? Nesciunt repellat labore totam sunt porro velit excepturi assumenda distinctio non? Eveniet a magnam doloribus odit voluptatum earum maiores ipsum fuga recusandae aliquam. Praesentium autem vel ipsum omnis eligendi ab et, quaerat nobis culpa dolores laborum neque harum consequatur in mollitia est asperiores excepturi qui, veniam sit officia nisi id libero! Natus ex, error eos aliquid rem, quis illum ratione fugit magnam non laborum dolores dignissimos reiciendis aspernatur nostrum cumque 

            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <label for="readmore 3"
                    data-more="READ MORE"
                    data-less="READ LESS"
                ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

            </div>
            
          </div>
          
          <div class="tab-item app-development">
 <img
             src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Group-149.png"
                alt="web development"
                class="tab-img1"
              />
            <div class="tab-content-left">
              <div class="box1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="readmore" id="readmore 8">
        <div class="content body">
            <div class="des"><h1 class="tab-heading">UI UX Design</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas sequi consectetur culpa eius aliquam, deserunt voluptatem quos distinctio atque, ad consequatur nemo totam fugit mollitia molestias natus exercitationem veritatis libero porro debitis? Et porro consequatur minima placeat harum iusto labore sed perspiciatis accusamus voluptatum ipsam esse illum fugiat, possimus vitae dolores officiis tenetur provident explicabo beatae nostrum aspernatur doloremque quos! Deserunt quisquam facere doloremque hic nisi, at earum facilis voluptatibus exercitationem distinctio! Deleniti, voluptatem ratione minima incidunt laboriosam repudiandae maiores cumque maxime fugit ex dolore ullam iusto, id ea dolorum reiciendis eaque asperiores. Magni ab tenetur doloremque! Harum totam laboriosam, quam corrupti dolorum nostrum ullam, temporibus expedita minima fuga, sapiente pariatur voluptatibus? Nesciunt repellat labore totam sunt porro velit excepturi assumenda distinctio non? Eveniet a magnam doloribus odit voluptatum earum maiores ipsum fuga recusandae aliquam. Praesentium autem vel ipsum omnis eligendi ab et, quaerat nobis culpa dolores laborum neque harum consequatur in mollitia est asperiores excepturi qui, veniam sit officia nisi id libero! Natus ex, error eos aliquid rem, quis illum ratione fugit magnam non laborum dolores dignissimos reiciendis aspernatur nostrum cumque 

            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <label for="readmore 8"
                    data-more="READ MORE"
                    data-less="READ LESS"
                ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cuando cambio las dimensiones, empieza el problema con el espacio debajo de esta manera:
[image: El punto negro abajo es en donde empieza el siguiente título]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que primero debes enfocarte en arreglar el layout de la página. Evita los `position: absolute` a toda costa.

Trata primero de crear un diseño limpio con flexbox o grid, mejor aún con un framework como bootstrap o tailwind y luego añade las animaciones.

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu ayuda.